# Serialization/Deserialization in Windows Forms with several levels

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, serialization, deserialization, windows-forms-designer

I'm currently working with Serialization/Deserialization on Windows Form app with several levels of classes. I have spent 5 days trying to debug this (from simple function StepInto with Breakpoints to closing down property by property) but to the same TargetInvocationException which happens in the Form class.

I will get there by explaining the levels first.

First of, the most top one which is like this:

```
[Serializable]
public enum SAI
{
    level1,
    level2,
    level3
}

[Serializable]
public class First:ISerializable
{
    public SAI something { get; set; }
    public double something1 { get; set; }
    public int something2 { get; set; }
```

and I have implemented the custom serialization/deserialization part

```
public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("something", something,typeof(SAI));
        info.AddValue("something1", something2, typeof(double));
        info.AddValue("something2", something2,typeof(int));
    }

    private First(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        something = (SAI)info.GetValue("something", typeof(SAI));
        something1 = (double)info.GetValue("something1",typeof(double));
        something2 = (int)info.GetValue("something2",typeof(int));
    }
```

While the next class is something like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class Second:ISerializable
{
  public String something3 { get; set; }
  public int something4 { get; set; }
  public bool something5 { get; set; }
  public double something6 { get; set; }
  public System.Drawing.Bitmap something7 { get; set; }
}
```

and the custom serialization/deserialization part:

```
private Second(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        something3 = (String)info.GetValue("something3",typeof(String));
        something4 = (int)info.GetValue("something4",typeof(int));
        something5 = (bool)info.GetValue("something5",typeof(bool));
        something6 = (double)info.GetValue("something6",typeof(double));
        something7 = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)info.GetValue("something7", typeof(System.Drawing.Bitmap));
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("something3", something3,typeof(String));
        info.AddValue("something4", something4,typeof(int));
        info.AddValue("something5", something5,typeof(bool));
        info.AddValue("something6", something6,typeof(double));
        info.AddValue("something7", something7,typeof(System.Drawing.Bitmap));
    }
```

Then the second level:

```
[Serializable]
public class Third :ISerializable
{
  public String something8 { get; set; }
  public int something9 { get; set; }
  public System.Drawing.Bitmap something10 { get; set; }
  public First first { get; set; }
  public List<Second> second { get; set; }
}
```

and the serialization/deserialization part:

```
private Third(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        something8 = (String)info.GetValue("something8",typeof(String));
        something9 = (int)info.GetValue("HeroWins",typeof(int));
        something10 = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)info.GetValue("something10", typeof(System.Drawing.Bitmap));
        first = (First)info.GetValue("first", typeof(First));
        second = (List<Second>)info.GetValue("second", typeof(Second));
    }
public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
      info.AddValue("something8", something8,typeof(String));
      info.AddValue("something9", something9,typeof(int));
      info.AddValue("something10", something10, typeof(System.Drawing.Bitmap));
      info.AddValue("first", first, typeof(First));
      info.AddValue("second", second, typeof(List<Second>));
    }
```

And finally the third level:

```
[Serializable]
public class Fourth:ISerializable
{
     public String something11 { get; set; }
     public List<Third> third { get; set; }
}
```

and the serialization/deserialization part:

```
private Fourth(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        something11 = (String)info.GetValue("something11",typeof(String));
        third = (List<Hero>)info.GetValue("third", typeof(List<Third>));
    }
public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("something11", Name,typeof(String));
        info.AddValue("third", third,typeof(List<Third>));
    }
```

**AND FINALLY** where the mistake happens :D

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
   private List<Fourth> fourth; // this is initialized in Constructor on first time
   private Third t1, t2, t3; // these are initialized in Constructor on first time

   private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        using (FileStream str = File.Create("Third.bin"))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(str, t1); 
            bf.Serialize(str, t2);
            bf.Serialize(str, t3);
        }

        using (FileStream str = File.Create("Fourth.bin"))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(str, fourth);
        }
    }

    private void VersusGlavno_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            using (FileStream str = File.OpenRead("Third.bin"))
            {
                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                t1 = (Third)bf.Deserialize(str); //first TargetInvocationException, returns NULL
                t2 = (Third)bf.Deserialize(str); //second TargetInvocationException, returns NULL
                t3 = (Third)bf.Deserialize(str); //third TargetInvocationException, returns NULL
            }
            using (FileStream str = File.OpenRead("Fourth.bin"))
            {
                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                fourth = null;
                fourth = (List<Fourth>)bf.Deserialize(str); //fourth TargetInvocationException, returns NULL
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: TargetInvocationException occurs when reflection tries to invoke something that throws an exception.  To better judge what's going on, please post the details of the TargetInvocationException.InnerException.

Comment: Thank you very much @PeterRitchie, solved the problem. I had serialized class B without giving the right name when I needed to deserialize it

Answer (score 1):

`TargetInvocationException` occurs when reflection tries to invoke something that throws an exception. To better judge what's going on, please post the details of the

> TargetInvocationException.InnerException